# How to override a tr:nth-child(2n)?

Tags: css

A site-wide style sheet has a directive of the form

```
#outerdiv tr:nth-child(2n) {
    background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

which I would like to override for the tables contained inside div `#innerdiv`, which in turn is contained inside div `#outerdiv`.

The only thing I've found works is:

```
#innerdiv tr:nth-child(2n) {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Which seems to me excessively specific, and probably very fragile.

Is there some other way to just *rescind* the site-wide directive?  Alternatively, is there a way to specify a background color for *all* the table rows within `#innerdiv`.

FWIW, the following does not work:

```
#innerdiv tr {
    background-color: #ffffff; !important;
}
```

Comment: It's `background-color: #ffffff !important;` not `background-color: #ffffff; !important;`

Comment: Try this selector: `#innerdiv > tr {background-color: #ffffff;}`

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
#innerdiv tr {
    background-color: #ffffff !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Depending on how your tables are nested, you can use the following code should the first table is a direct child of `#outerdiv`:

```
table tr {
    background-color: #fff
}
#outerdiv > table tr:nth-child(2n) {
    background-color: #cccc;
}
```